# Vue 3 - Emit event from child component within a slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm looking at upgrading to v3 and was disappointed to see inline-template has been removed. Therefore I'm trying to convert to use a scoped slot instead.

I have defined the following list component:

```
<template>
    <slot :items="filteredItems" :page="page" :totalPages="totalPages" :onPageChanged="onPageChanged"></slot>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            items: {
                type: Array
            },
            initialPage: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1,
            },
            pageSize: {
                type: Number,
                default: 10
            }
        },
        beforeCreate() {
            this.page = this.initialPage;
        },
        computed: {
            filteredItems() {
                return this.items.slice((this.page - 1) * this.pageSize, this.page * this.pageSize);
            },
            totalPages() {
                return Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.pageSize);
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onPageChanged(page) {
                console.log('Page changed!!!');

                this.page = page;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Which is called like so:

```
<list :items="[ { foo: 'A' }, { foo: 'B' }, { foo: 'C' } ]" :page-size="2" #="{ items, page, totalPages, onPageChanged }">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in items">{{ item.foo }}</li>
    </ul>
    <pager :page="page" :total-pages="totalPages" @pageChanged="onPageChanged"></pager>
</list>
```

Here's the pager component:

```
<template>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item" v-if="hasPreviousPage"><a href="#" @click="changePage(1)" class="page-link">&laquo;</a></li>
        <li class="page-item" v-if="hasPreviousPage"><a href="#" @click="changePage(page - 1)" class="page-link">&#8249;</a></li>
        <li v-for="page in pages" :class="['page-item', { active: page.isActive }]"><a href="#" @click="changePage(page.name)" class="page-link">{{ page.name }}</a></li>
        <li class="page-item disabled" v-if="page < totalPages - 2"><span class="page-link"> ... </span></li>
        <li class="page-item" v-if="page < totalPages - 2"><a href="#" @click="changePage(totalPages)" class="page-link">{{ totalPages }}</a></li>
        <li class="page-item" v-if="hasNextPage"><a href="#" @click="changePage(page + 1)" class="page-link">&#8250;</a></li>
        <li class="page-item" v-if="hasNextPage"><a href="#" @click="changePage(totalPages)" class="page-link">&raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            page: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            totalPages: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        },
        computed: {
            hasPreviousPage() {
                return this.page > 1;
            },
            hasNextPage() {
                return this.page < this.totalPages;
            },
            pages() {
                const range = [];

                for (let i = this.page <= 2 ? 1 : this.page - 2; i <= (this.page >= this.totalPages - 2 ? this.totalPages : this.page + 2); i++) {
                    range.push({
                        name: i,
                        isActive: this.page == i
                    });
                }

                return range;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changePage(page, e = event) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Trigger the page changed event.
                this.$emit('pageChanged', page);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

However whenever I try to change the page, the `changePage` method is invoked which emits the `pageChanged` event, but it doesn't invoke the `onPageChanged` method within the list component.

I'd appreciate if someone could show me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#event-names        
*"v-on event listeners inside DOM templates will be automatically transformed to lowercase (due to HTML's case-insensitivity), so `@myEvent` would become `@myevent` -- making myEvent impossible to listen to."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event name should be written in `kebab-case` format as follows :

```
this.$emit('page-changed', page);
```

and use it like `@page-changed="onPageChanged`

Comment: Thanks I knew it would be something obvious.