# Prevent moving to next tab vue.js wizard

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using vue.js wizard but my issue is i cannot prevent tab, i have found many links that shows before change event is working, but in my case it is not working. Is there any script which is missing, Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<form-wizard @onComplete="onComplete">
<tab-content title="Step 1" :selected="true" :before-change="()=>beforeTabSwitch(1)">

</tab-content>
<tab-content title="Step 2">

</tab-content>
<tab-content title="Step 3">

</tab-content>

 beforeTabSwitch: async(tab) => {
     let flag = false;
     await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        flag = true;
        resolve("done");
      }, 1500);
    }).then();
    return flag;
   }
```

FormWizard.vue.js

```
<template>
    <div class="vue-step-wizard">
        <div class="step-header">
        <div class="step-progress">
            <div class="bar progressbar" :style="{ width: progress + '%' }">
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="step-pills">
            <li @click.prevent.stop="selectTab(index)" class="step-item" :class="{ 'active': tab.isActive, 'validated': tab.isValidated }" v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" v-bind:key="`tab-${index}`">
                <a class="step-link" href="#">
                        <span class="tabStatus">{{index+1}} </span> 
                        <span class="tabLabel">{{tab.title}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="step-body card">
            <form>
                <slot></slot>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="step-footer">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <template v-if="!submitSuccess">
                  <button @click="previousTab" :disabled="currentTab === 0" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Previous</button>
                  <button @click="nextTab" v-if="currentTab < totalTabs - 1" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Next</button>
                  <button @click="onSubmit" v-if="currentTab === totalTabs - 1" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Submit</button>
                </template>
                <template v-else>
                  <button @click="reset" class="btn btn-success">Reset</button>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { store } from "./store.js";
export default {
    name: 'form-wizard',
    data(){
        return{
            tabs: [],
            currentTab : 0,
            totalTabs : 0,
            storeState: store.state,
            submitSuccess : false,
            progress: 0,
            isValidationSupport: false
        }
    },
    mounted(){
            this.tabs = this.$children;
            this.totalTabs = this.tabs.length;
            this.currentTab = this.tabs.findIndex((tab) => tab.isActive === true);

            //Select first tab if none is marked selected
            if(this.currentTab === -1 && this.totalTabs > 0){  
                this.tabs[0].isActive = true;
                this.currentTab = 0;
            }
            
            //Setup Initial Progress
            this.progress = ((this.currentTab + 1) / this.totalTabs * 100);

    },

    updated(){
        /*
          Using this lifehook - since store variable gets updated after component is mounted
          isValidationSupport checks if user is looking to perform validation on each step
        */
        this.isValidationSupport = (Object.keys(this.storeState.v).length !== 0 && this.storeState.v.constructor === Object) ? true : false;
    },

    methods:{
        previousTab(){
    
            this._switchTab(this.currentTab - 1);

            this.$emit('onPreviousStep'); 
        },

        nextTab(){

            if(this._validateCurrentTab() === false)
                return;

            this._switchTab(this.currentTab + 1);    

            this.$emit('onNextStep');          
              
        },

        reset(){

           this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
             tab.isActive = false;
             tab.isValidated = false;
           });

           this._switchTab(0);
           this.submitSuccess = false;
           this.storeState.v.$reset();

           this.$emit('onReset');
        },

        changeStatus(){
            this.submitSuccess = true;
        },

        selectTab(index){
            if(index < this.currentTab){
              this._switchTab(index);
            }

            if(this._validateCurrentTab() === false){
                return;
            }

            if(this.tabs[index - 1].isValidated === false){
                return;
            }

            this._switchTab(index);
            
        },


        onSubmit(){
            if(this._validateCurrentTab() === false)
                return;
            this.$emit('onComplete');
        },

        _switchTab(index){
            //Disable all tabs
            this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
              tab.isActive = false;
            });

            this.currentTab = index;
            this.tabs[index].isActive = true;

            this.progress = ((this.currentTab + 1) / this.totalTabs * 100);
        },

        _validateCurrentTab(){
            if(!this.isValidationSupport)  //Check if user wants to validate 
                return true;

            this.storeState.v.$touch();

            if (this.storeState.v.$invalid) {
                this.tabs[this.currentTab].isValidated = false;
                return false;
            }

            this.tabs[this.currentTab].isValidated = true;

            return true;
        }
    },
    watch:{
       currentTab(){
          store.setCurrentTab(this.currentTab);
       }
    }
    
}
</script>
<style>

  .progressbar {
    transition: width 1s ease;
  } 

  .vue-step-wizard{
    background-color: #F7F8FC;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 40px;
  }

  .step-progress{
    height: 1rem;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem 0rem;
  }

  .step-progress .bar{
      content: '';
      height: 1rem;
      border-radius: 1rem;
      background-color: #4B8AEB;
  }

  .step-pills{
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.15)!important;
  }

  .step-pills .step-item{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
  }


   .step-pills .step-item a{
     text-decoration: none;
      color: #2f2f2f;
      font-size: 12px;
   }

   .step-pills .step-item.active{
      border: 1px solid #4B8AEB;
   }

   .step-pills .step-item.validated{
      border: 1px solid #008011;
   }

   .step-body{
     background-color: white;
     margin-left: auto;
     padding: 1rem;
     border-radius: 1rem;
     box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.15)!important;
   }

  .step-footer {
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 1rem 0rem;
    text-align: right;
    background: #fff;
}

  .step-button{
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 30rem;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: #22292f;
    color: rgba(34,41,47,var(--text-opacity));
    padding: 0.5rem 1.25rem;
    font-size: .875rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }

  .step-button-next{
    background-color: #126fde;
  }

  .step-button-previous{
    background-color: #3deaba;
  }

  .step-button-submit{
    background-color: #4fa203;
  }

  .step-button-reset{
    background-color: #037da2;
  }

  /** Wizard Ends */
  .tabStatus{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1.5rem;
      height: 1.5rem;
      margin-right: .5rem;
      line-height: 1.5rem;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.38);
      border-radius: 50%;
  }


</style>
```

> store.js

```
export const store = {
    state: {
      currentTab: 0,
      v: {},
    },
    setCurrentTab (newValue) {
        this.state.currentTab = newValue;
    },
    setValidation(newValue){
      this.state.v = newValue;
    }
  };
```

TabContent:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="isActive">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'tab-content',
    props:{
        selected: {
            default: false,
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data(){
        return{
            isActive: false,
            isValidated : false,
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.isActive = this.selected;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64106118/vue-3-emit-event-from-child-component-within-a-slot/64106357#64106357 ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: I have to call it on before change event link : https://binarcode.github.io/vue-form-wizard/#/